# Retaining Fragment backstack on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

**CONSTRUCTION**

I've got `Activity` that holds a "path" made of `Fragments`.
The User goes from `Fragment1` to `Fragment2` and then to `Fragment3` filling up the required informations. Nothing fancy here just plain `backStack` and `.replace` made on `Fragments`.

**QUESTION**

**How** should I retain that information when orientation changes to get my `backStack` back the way it was before orientation change?

**IDEAS**

The only idea I have is to insert into `saveInstanceState` the last visible `Fragment` and recreate things from there but it feels really hacky and I think in the long run it's going to make some major problems.

/////////////**UPDATE**//////////////

It looks like nowadays Android is capable of doing it on its own as long as you are following the guidelines provided by [ARTICLE](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backstack itself is saved and loaded automatically with the activity.
[Here's an article](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en) how Android does save and load activity and fragment states.
What you should care of is implementing the same logic of saving and restoring states for each fragment.

Comment: Since v0.10.0, StatedFragment is now marked deprecated :C

But it guided me here http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that. I'll update my answer for future reference.

Comment: In the followup article author does not tackle my problem, he explained how Fragments are recreated right now. It does not provide the information on how to retain data from `backStack`. Right know the library only provide tools to receive `onActivityResult` in nested `Fragments`

Comment: If I understood correctly, the backstack should be saved and loaded automatically without any code. You just have to handle the view of each fragment individually

Comment: Well to my suprise it really does work. I was confused because `SupportFragmentManager` count was always `1` after retaning instance. Looks like the case is closed. Thanks for help mate.

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted but you need to get rid of the info about the library. It might cause some misunderstandings to potential readers since it's not connected to problem.